# finding strings in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, match

I have a python list `['100', '20.0', '?', 'a', '0']`. The list contains real strings `'?', 'a'` and ints and floats coded in strings. I am trying to find the (real) strings `'?', 'a'` in the list.

Comment: You want to check if the value is an alphanumeric character?

Comment: What about strings `nan`, `-inf` etc.? They are valid floats in Python

Comment: Try to parse each element, catch errors and save those "invalid" values as your "real strings"

Comment: Yes I am trying to find all the elements (including nan and inf) that are not floats

Comment: You have some useful answers and discussions on this topic in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float

Comment: @locke14, Thankyou. This is what I am looking for. I can simply use `try` and `except`.

Comment: Should strings such as `a1` be counted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = ['100', '20.0', '?', 'a', '0']

result = []
for item in data:
    if not any(c.isnumeric() for c in item): # check if number exist in string
        result.append(item)
print (result)
```

output:

```
['?', 'a']
```

what is equal to list comprehension:

```
print ([item for item in data if not any(c.isnumeric() for c in item) ])
```

output:

```
['?', 'a']
```